# Macro to copy and paste based on column headings

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm very new to writing Macros in Excel, and have done a bit of looking around to try and solve my problem, but I haven't found a solution yet that works.

I'm trying to write a Macro to do the following:

I'm trying to copy data from Sheet 1, Workbook 1 based on column headings (so for example, I want to copy all the data under the column name "Sort"). The number of rows of data in this row may increase/decrease. I then want to paste this data into Sheet 2, Workbook 2 under the column name "Name". Columns may be added/removed from both workbooks, which is why I want to write the macro to copy based on the column name rather than a column number.

I have been using the below code, which I've tried putting together based on similar but slightly different requests I've found online, but when I run the macro, nothing much happens - I've written the Macro in Workbook 2 and it just opens Workbook 1.

If anyone can see something wrong with my code or suggest an alternative, I'd be extremely grateful for any help. Thanks!!!

```
Sub CopyProjectName()
    Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet
    Set CurrentWS = ActiveSheet
    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Set SourceWS = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim SourceHeaderRow As Integer: SourceHeaderRow = 1
    Dim SourceCell As Range, sRange As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim TargetWS As Worksheet
    Set TargetWS = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim TargetHeader As Range
    Set TargetHeader = TargetWS.Range("A1:AX1")
    Dim RealLastRow As Long
    Dim SourceCol As Integer

    Range("B2").Select
    SourceWS.Activate
    LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set sRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Cells(1, LastCol))
    With sRange
        Set Rng = .Find(What:="Sort", _
                        After:=.Cells(1), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Rng, Cells(LastRow, Rng.Column)).Copy
            TargetWS.Activate
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Paste
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have "Sort" as one of my headings in Sheet 1 - it is currently in A1, but might not always be. I got most of the first part (the copy part) from looking at other codes, but the last bit (the paste part) I'm really not sure on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbook1.xlsx` and `Workbook2.xlsm` have to be open for the code bellow

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyProjectName()
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet, targetWS As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long, srcRow As Range
    Dim found1 As Range, found2 As Range

    Set sourceWS = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Needs to be open
    Set targetWS = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Needs to be open

    With sourceWS
        lastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set srcRow = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, lastCol))
        Set found1 = srcRow.Find(What:="Sort", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not found1 Is Nothing Then
            lastCol = targetWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Set srcRow = targetWS.Range("A1", targetWS.Cells(1, lastCol))
            Set found2 = srcRow.Find(What:="Name", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not found2 Is Nothing Then
                lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, found1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range(.Cells(2, found1.Column), .Cells(lastRow, found1.Column)).Copy
                found2.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I'm wondering though, with this macro, it copies the entire column from the original Workbook. Is there anyway of copying the content from row 2 down (i.e. not the header) and pasting this under the new heading in Workbook 2 ("Name")?

Comment: Almost! I'm still getting the original header from Sheet1 appearing in B2... It now appears under the new heading in B1. Is there any way of not coping the original header, just the data contained in that column?

Comment: You're welcome! Also, please accept the answer as it provides a working solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyProjectName()
    ' Define source and target workbooks
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

    ' Check if the source workbook is open, and open it if not
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If sourceWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        ' Workbook is not open, so open it
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("Path_to_Workbook1.xlsx")
    End If

    ' Check if the target workbook is open, and open it if not
    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If targetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        ' Workbook is not open, so open it
        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("Path_to_Workbook2.xlsm")
    End If

    ' Define source and target worksheets
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet

    ' Set the source and target worksheets
    Set sourceWorksheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set targetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ' Define the column name to copy from source to target
    Dim columnName As String
    columnName = "Sort"

    ' Find the column with the specified column name in the source worksheet
    Dim sourceColumn As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourceColumn = sourceWorksheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=columnName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not sourceColumn Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the last row with data in the source column
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = sourceWorksheet.Cells(sourceWorksheet.Rows.Count, sourceColumn.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Copy the data from the source column
        sourceWorksheet.Range(sourceColumn, sourceWorksheet.Cells(lastRow, sourceColumn.Column)).Copy

        ' Find the corresponding column in the target worksheet
        Dim targetColumn As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set targetColumn = targetWorksheet.Rows(1).Find(What:="Name", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not targetColumn Is Nothing Then
            ' Paste the data into the target column
            targetWorksheet.Cells(1, targetColumn.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If

        Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Clear the clipboard
    End If

    ' Close the workbooks (if they were opened by this macro)
    If sourceWorkbook.Name = "Workbook1.xlsx" Then
        sourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If

    If targetWorkbook.Name = "Workbook2.xlsm" Then
        targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to provide some context with your code? How does your code resolve the question? And, possibly, how is your code better than the original answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).